# Class cast exception while adding a second tree node to PriorityQueue

Tags: java

I am trying to print a binary tree by BFS.

my implementation is with a PriorityQueue.
in the beginning i insert root into PriorityQueue.
then in loop, i pull a node from PriorityQueue, print it, and insert his childs(if thay are not null) into PriorityQueue.
why when inserting the second node, i get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

this is my code:

class main:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Tree tree = new Tree();
    }
}
```

class Node:

```
    public class Node {

    public Node(){}

    public Node(int num)
    {
        value = num;
    }
    private int value;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Node getLeft() {
        return left;
    }
    public void setLeft(Node left) {
        this.left = left;
    }
    public Node getRight() {
        return right;
    }
    public void setRight(Node right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

}
```

class tree:

```
    public class Tree {

    private Node root;

    public Tree()
    {
        root = new Node(5);
        Node node2 = new Node(2);
        Node node10 = new Node(10);
        Node node8 = new Node(8);
        Node node6 = new Node(6);
        Node node15 = new Node(15);
        root.setRight(node10);
        root.setLeft(node2);
        node10.setRight(node15);
        node10.setLeft(node8);
        node8.setLeft(node6);

        printToWidth(root);
    }

    public void printToWidth(Node node)
    {
        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
         queue.add(node);
         while( !(queue.isEmpty()))
         {
             Node n = queue.poll();
             System.out.println(n.getValue());
             if (n.getLeft() != null)
                 queue.add(n.getLeft());
             if (n.getRight() != null)
                 queue.add(n.getRight());
         }
         System.out.println("end printToWidth");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got two options:

- Make `Node` implement `Comparable<Node>`, so that the elements can be inserted according to their [natural ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue()).  This is likely the easier of the two.

  ```
  public int compareTo(Node other) {
      return value - other.getValue();
  }
  ```
- Use a [custom `Comparator<Node>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator)) and supply a `compare` method there, with an initial capacity.

  ```
  PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(10, new Comparator<Node>() {
          public int compare(Node left, Node right) {
              return left.getValue() - other.getValue();
          }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you, make `Node` implement `Comparable<Node>`.

You can insert the first node because it has nothing to compare to, so the comparison is not needed.

Comment: thanks. how to fix it? changing definition of Tree class to:         public class Tree implements Comparable<Tree>,  dint help.

Comment: The exception is: `Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`. The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add%28E%29) of `PriorityQueue#add()` says that `E` (i.e. `Node`) need to be comparable, or a `ClassCastException` will be thrown and you recommend to implement the interface on `Tree`?